# GreenGeeks versus WebFaction for Web mapping

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, hosting, geonode, ushahidi

Am looking into choosing a hosting service to test out and ultimately deploy a web mapping service. I want to test out Mapserver, Geoserver, Geonode and Ushahidi towards making a decision so looking into a hosting service. Does anyone have any advice/experience with GreenGeeks or WebFaction ?

Comment: FWIW, I've used WebFaction for hosting for years now, and they are a great company with fantastic support. Everyone there is very savvy and a human replies to tickets very promptly. Their tech stack is top notch as well and they don't shove 5,000 sites onto a shared server either. I'm pretty sure you can install just about anything as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I've had similar positive comments for Webfaction. It seems to be going higher up my list. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Short answer, consider an entry-level VPS service provider. I am using [Host1Plus](http://www.host1plus.com/#hostingservices=vps-hosting) (silver plan) for basic VPS hosting, and [Contabo](https://contabo.com/?show=vps) for more resource intensive deployments. Other popular options include [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) and [Linode](https://www.linode.com/pricing). All of these providers have options for $5-$15/month.

## Longer answer

Mapserver, Geoserver, Geonode, and Ushahidi all have different system requirements. Most of them need more resources and/or user permissions than are often available shared hosts. This means that you might have difficulty trying these applications on a shared host, such as GreenGeeks or WebFaction.

### Mapserver and Geonode

Mapserver and Geonode will probably require a VPS service, as mentioned in the short answer. This is primarily because of installation and system resource requirements.

Mapserver [installation](http://mapserver.org/installation/unix.html) is non-trivial, and I have never had success with that one.

Geonode has [great packaging for Ubuntu 12.04](http://geonode.org/#install) (at the time of writing). It also has really high server requirements (recommending 6Gb of RAM). For Geonode, you might consider a VPS provider such as Contabo.

### Geoserver

I have successfully installed Geoserver on WebFaction, so this might be a viable option for you as well.

Basically, follow the WebFaction [community instructions for installing the Tomcat server](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/4116/install-tomcat-howto-or-step-by-step-tutorial), then follow the [Geoserver WAR installation instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html).

### Ushahidi

Ushahidi 2.x will run on most shared hosts. I have successfully installed Ushahidi on GreenGeeks, for example. All it needs is PHP and a MySQL database to run. Follow the [Ushahidi installation guide](https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Installing+the+Ushahidi+Platform) on your shared host.